# Can't enable Symantac Anti-Virus Auto-Protect

Tags: anti-virus, symantec

I am having trouble enabling the Symantec Anti-Virus auto-protect feature.

[image]

For some reason, after right clicking and choosing *Enable Auto-Protect*, the option is not turned on.

Where should I look to enable the feature?

Comment: Whenever I come across a computer with Symantec Anti-Virus, my first reaction is to convince the owner to uninstall it.

Comment: I tend to have the same inclination. I prefer free, strong products. Maybe you could go with AVG free 8.5

Comment: I used AVG until it deleted some vital files. I now use Avast.

Comment: Back-up dude. And working programs help to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, "Symantec Antivirus" service was disabled...
After starting the service, I was able to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the right place to enable the feature. Unfortunately, this seems to be all too common problem with SAV.

I'd start by diagnosing the issue by checking to make sure of all SAV's services are running, and seeing how it runs under safe-mode. As well, have you made any software changes recently?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in the past with some of my machines running Symatec Anti-Virus, I would recommend reinstalling the AV software.

Just as a side note you can use free "lighter weight" AV software" if it is a home machine:
http://danielk.org/blog/2009/05/21/windows-antivirus-protection/